# Writing a letter using scanf in C

Tags: c, scanf

I was given this exercise:

> Imagine, somebody wants to write a letter. Each sentence is entered using a single scanf-command execution. Each sentence is to be stored in a character array of
>   optimal length. If the user enters a line which only consists of a dash (-), the text is
>   assumed to be finished. After all text has been entered, it is to be printed out to the
>   console.

I couldn't quite get what it means but I decided to try and write an email using scanf

```
#include <stdio.h>         
int main()        
{          

char name1[100];       
char mail1[9999];     
char name2[100];        
printf("Dear ");      
scanf("%s", name1);     
scanf("%s", mail1);      
printf("Sincerely,");         
scanf("%s", name2);       


return 0;      
}
```

This is what I could write. After I write someone's name after it prints "Dear", I just write the body of the letter but if I write more than one word it doesn't let me write anything after Sincerely

Comment: The `%s` format specifier reads *space-delimited **words***.

Comment: You should use `fgets`.

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your 3rd `scanf` skipped because you have put spaces between in second `scanf`. To avoid this use `get()` method instead of `scanf()`

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char name1[100];       
    char mail1[9999];     
    char name2[100]; 

    printf("Dear "); 

    gets(name1);
    gets(mail1);

    printf("Sincerely, "); 

    gets(name2);

    return 0;   
}
```

**But** If you want to try this using only `scanf()` follow this code.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char name1[100];       
    char mail1[9999];     
    char name2[100]; 

    printf("Dear ");

    scanf("%[^\n]%*c", name1);
    scanf("%[^\n]%*c", mail1);

    printf("Sincerely, "); 

    scanf("%[^\n]%*c", name2);

    return 0;   
}
```

**output of both codes -:**

```
Dear Son                                                                                                            
I love you                                                                                                          
Sincerely, Your Mom
```

Comment: Ohhh thanks, I tried using fgets but it just skipped it completely, is there anything i can do about the dash by the way?

Comment: what dash? Can you explain further?

Comment: So inputting a dash (-) is supposed to end the sentence, one sentence is supposed to be one scanf according to the exercise I think.

Comment: Yes it is. If you want to write like paragraphs you have use another few char arrays.

Comment: Could you explain how the dash ends a sentence? I tried using an if statement and loops but couldn't get it right

Comment: when you enter dash you want to display "Sincerely" message am I correct.

Comment: No, I think the dash should end the sentence so I can write the next one and the final dash must display "sincerely"

Comment: use fullstop to end a sentence. Real challenge is write multiple sentences by pressing `Enter`. If you enter `-` all paragraphs will stop and display "Sincerely" message. I can do it for you.

Comment: That'd be too much to ask, wouldn't it?

Comment: No,It's not too much. I think you have to raise another question. Your problem is too much to this question. Ask new question by mentioning your new problem.

Comment: So should I ask again but about the dash?

Comment: Yes, start a new question add code what have you tried with dash and explain what you really want to archive.

Answer (score 3):

your program should do the following:

```
while (1)
{
    scnaf into a fixed length buffer;
    if the buffer equals to "-"
        break the loop;
    duplicate the buffer;
    add the duplicate to any structure (like a linked list);
}

run over the list and print all the lines.
```

regarding `scanf`, a naive call will not work since it reads only aword. Use `fgets` or a more permissive scan format specifier. Googling it I found this option:

```
scanf("%[^\n]", str);
```